# Grep output unreadable when redirect to file

Tags: bash, grep

I have a script that receives an list of IDs as the 1st parameter and does a grep for each id against the file given at the second parameter:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    grep --line-buffered -Pzo '(>'"$line"')(.|\n)+?(?=>)' "$2"
done < "$1"
```

It outputs normally to the terminal

```
>XP_002012335.1 uncharacterized protein Dmoj_GI21415 [Drosophila mojavensis]
MAESRFNQLHLSAT 
...
```

But if *redirect the output to a file* like so:

```
./grep_script.sh id_query subject > out.txt
```

My `out.txt` is corrupted:

```
3e58 505f 3030 3230 3132 3333 352e 3120
756e 6368 6172 6163 7465 7269 7a65 6420
7072 6f74 6569 6e20 446d 6f6a 5f47 4932
3134 3135 205b 4472 6f73 6f70 6869 6c61
206d 6f6a 6176 656e 7369 735d 0a4d 4145
```

Comment: @KamilCuk It doesn't look like the OP is both reading from and writing to `out.txt`.

Comment: The hex dump looks fine if I convert it back to ASCII. What are you using to produce this hex dump? The commands you show do not produce this output.

Comment: @tripleee yeah, the hex output is the textual output, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The -z option in grep replaces the newline character with a *null* character.
When opening the `out.txt` the null character causes problems when displaying it in the text editor.

The same problem doesn't occur when printing to the terminal.